# How to pass arguments in @Analyzer in annotation in Apache Lucene / Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am analyzing Lucene with no Stop Words using Annotations

```
 @Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.NO, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class)),
```

But i want to pass arguments in StandardAnalyzer

```
StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36, Collections.emptySet())
```

Could anyone suggest how to do that in annotations on Column itself